# How should I implement a function to find indices of non-true elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, boolean, ecmascript-5

I have a function named `uncompletedSteps()`:

```
function uncompletedSteps(completedSteps) {
    // completedSteps is an array
}
```

This function should examine `completedSteps` and return the index of all `completedSteps` elements that are not equal to `true`:

```
if (completedSteps[i] === true) {
    // add to return list
}
```

In other words, if have:

```
var completedSteps = [
    true,
    null,
    true
];
```

Then `uncompletedSteps()` should return `[0, 2]`.

What should this `uncompletedSteps()` look like? (ECMAScript5 okay.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reduce`:

```
function uncompletedSteps(steps){
   return steps.reduce(function(memo, entry, i) { 
      return memo.concat(entry ? i : []);
   }, [])
}
```

Using `forEach`:

```
function uncompletedSteps(steps){
   var uncompleted = [];
   steps.forEach(function(entry,i) { 
      if(entry) uncompleted.push(i); 
   })
   return uncompleted;
}
```

Using `map` and `filter`

```
function uncompletedSteps(steps){
   return steps.map(function(entry, i) {
      return entry ? i : null;
   }).filter(function(entry) {
      return entry != null;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = [];
for ( var i = 0; i<completedSteps.length; i++ ) {
  if(completedSteps[i]) {
    count.push(i);
  }
}
return count;
```

Comment: I actually already implemented this. My question is whether there's a more succinct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [true, true, null, true];
arr.map(function(el, i) { 
    return el ? i : -1; 
}).filter(function(el) {
    return el != -1;
})
```

Returns:

```
 [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

> This function should examine completedSteps and return the index of all completedSteps elements that are not equal to true:

Use the following process for backwards compatibility:

- multiple replaces to insert the string `null` for values [converted to empty strings](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5#sec-15.4.4.5)
- one `replace` to remove `true`
- another `replace` with a replacer callback to insert indices
- another `replace` to remove a leading comma
- another `replace` to remove paired commas

For example:

```
function foo(match, offset, fullstring)
  {
  foo.i = foo.i + 1 || 0;
  if (match === "true") 
    {
    return "";
    }
  else
    {
    return foo.i;
    }
  }

function uncompletedSteps(node)
  {
  return String(node).replace(/^,/ , "null,").replace(/,$/ , ",null").replace(/,,/g , ",null,").replace(/[^,]+/g, foo).replace(/^,/,"").replace(/,,/g,",")
  }

var completedSteps = [
    null,
    true,
    false,
    true,
    null,
    false,
    true,
    null
];

uncompletedSteps(completedSteps); // "0,2,4,5,7"
```